# Patent Application 20120173688

Tags: telecommunications, maintenance, coordination, us20120173688

What's novel about Patent Application [US 20120173688](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120173688) ? Is there prior art?

Comment: As explained in the FAQs, the ideal question of this sort demonstrates that the questioner has already done some homework. It might be hard to motivate people to do research on something without knowing what has already been done and what the motivation/outrage is.

Comment: See the format discussed here for suggestions: **[What should an ideal prior art request look like?](http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/q/47/1)**.

Answer (score 1):

A non-final office action was issued in December citing [Zothner 6751657](http://www.google.com/patents/US6751657). You can look the application in question up at [USPTO Public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/external/portal/pair/)  and see what else the examiner has cited and why.